# How to show records in section with heading from activeDataProvider in yii2

Tags: yii2, cactivedataprovider, yii-widgets

My database structure is as follows

```
id :    item    :    name   : price
1  : framework  : bootstrap : 90
1  : framework  : zend : 100
1  : framework  : drupal : 150
1  : responsive : no        : 0
1  : responsive : yes       : 50
```

I want to render result as rows which have same item must have that item name as section heading and rest of the data should be displayed under that section as

**FRAMEWORK**

```
Name      : Price
Bootstrap : 90
Zend      : 100
Drupal    : 150
```

**RESPONSIVE**

```
Name    : Price
None    : 0
Yes     : 50
```

How can i done this with active data provider, data widgets or there may be another method

Comment: Do you want to show all tables in the same page or you would select an item (framework, responsive, ...) and show only that one?

Comment: Actually this is only a single table and i want to show all items(framework, responsie, etc) at same page but with sections to differentiate them.

Comment: Then I would not know how to do it with a sindle dataProvider/GridView. The easiest thing to do would be order the records by item and filter them with a dropdown in the header. Otherwise, I would use different dataProvders/GridViews

Comment: I just remembdered [this](http://demos.krajee.com/group-grid#example-6), I think that it is exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you override GridView's renderTableRow. if you detect a value-change on the column you want to group, just insert a custom group heading row.

```
<?php
class GroupGridView extends \yii\grid\GridView 
{
    public $groupingColumn = null;
    public $groupingText   = null;

    public function renderTableRow ($model, $key, $index)
    {
        if ($this->groupingColumn == null)
            return parent::renderTableRow($model, $key, $index);

        $models = $this->dataProvider->models;
        $result = '';
        if ($index < count($models) - 1 && ($index == 0 || $models[$index][$this->groupingColumn] != $models[$index + 1][$this->groupingColumn])) {
            $result = sprintf('<tr class="grouping"><td colspan="%d">%s</td></tr>', count($this->columns), ($this->groupingText == null ? $models[$index]->{$this->groupingColumn} : (is_callable($this->groupingText) ? call_user_func($this->groupingText, $model, $key, $index) : $this->groupingText)));
        }
        return $result . parent::renderTableRow($model, $key, $index);
    }
}

$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'      => \common\models\Task::find()->orderBy(['customer_id' => SORT_ASC]),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 100,
    ],
]);

echo GroupGridView::widget([
    'groupingColumn' => 'item',
    'groupingText' => function($model, $key, $index) {
        return sprintf('--- %s --- %s --- %d', $model->item, $key, $index);
    },
    'dataProvider'   => $dataProvider
])

?>
```

keep in mind that you have to sort by the grouping column.